# Convert PostGIS geometry column to a vector of Point2D in a PostgreSQL extension

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm writing a PostgreSQL extension that should do a certain mathematical operations on a geometry field. However all I really need to make it work is give it coordinates as `std::vector<Point2d>`.

So how can one extract coordinates from geometry column, either using PostGIS helper methods or directly? Is it even possible?

Comment: What is the geometry type?

Comment: It is a lineString.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using SQL, you could use [ST_DumpPoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) to get at the points.

But inside an extension, you need a more direct access to the geometry object. The internal storage format used by PostGIS changes between versions, so you cannot use it unless you put your code into the PostGIS library (if that is even possible in your system). So the best method to get a geometry object is as a [WKB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#Well-known_binary)-formatted blob; Postgres will automatically convert the geometry into WKB if you declare your function to have a `bytea` parameter. (WKB is defined in the [OGC Simple Feature Access specification](https://www.ogc.org/standards/sfa).)

Comment: I was already considering to either bundle `liblwgeom` part of `postgis` into my extension or load appropriate conversion methods from `postgis.so` dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract coordianates from a geometry column quite easily:

For x:

```
st_x(geometry_column)
```

For y:

```
st_y(geometry_column)
```

Documentation:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html